# ngx-slick - slick.js - viewing 3 slides - scrolling only one

Tags: slider, carousel, slick.js

I am using ngx-slick. I have a slider with
`slidesToShow=3` and `slidesToScroll=1;`

The thing is that when I scroll the carousel, I can scroll with my mouse more than one slide, but then it goes back and scrolls exactly one slide like I set in the config.

Can you show me the direction where to look to LOCK the carousel after scrolling exactly one slide, not being possible to scroll further (just one slide at a time)?

I read a lot of topics on the internet, but nothing really relates to this specific problem.

Comment: hey had the same problem but set slidesToShow=1 and slidesToScrol=1, behaves exactly how you  want it to